# how to submit the form before remove the tag jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this function:

```
    function Nextthing (){

    $('.iframe').remove();

    $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).remove();


    $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).after('<tr class="iframe"><td colspan=10><iframe  src="/msg.html?msgId='+$('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td a').eq(0).text()+'&constant=1"></iframe></td></tr>');

}
```

as you can see the first remove is an iframe, and inside that iframe is a form with a submit button. when i press it it removes the iframe but doesn't submit. how can i submit before the removal?

thanks!

html of iframe looks like:

```
<body>
<table>
<div>
<form>
<div>
<table>
<div>
<form>
</body>
```

Comment: It's the fourth time that you have posted this question, I think you should post the markup or create a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: i'm trying to detail everything so o can resolve this in steps. now everything is working but if i remove the iframe with that form the form won't submit, which is normal because i remove it so i need a solution to submit before removal

Comment: @undefined can you provide some help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snipet, just fix the Selector form is form has a class or id.

```
function Nextthing (){
    $('.iframe').contents().find("form").submit(); //Find Form inside the iFrame and submit it.

    $('.iframe').remove();

    $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).remove();


    $('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).after('<tr class="iframe"><td colspan=10><iframe  src="/msg.html?msgId='+$('.table').eq(1).find('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td a').eq(0).text()+'&constant=1"></iframe></td></tr>');

}
```

Comment: and: $('.iframe').contents().find("body form").eq(1).submit();

Comment: .eq(1) will return you the second form in selector, try .eq(0) @Jimmy

Comment: yes but as you see there's two forms my form that  i need to submit is the second: it has textaera and input of submit

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your removal:

```
$(".iframe").contents().find(yourform).submit();
```

**Edit**
Maybe try this instead of the remove code:

```
$(".iframe").contents().find("form").submit(function(){
    $('.iframe').remove();
});
```

Comment: Then you need to make a working example... (on jsFiddle for example)